# Converting two lists into a dictionary using built in list function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been trying this for weeks! I tried this for weeks and all i get is nothing!
I searched internet and also the great **STACK OVERFLOW** but I couldn't find the one i need for!
Well normally if we try to change lists into dictionary we would get space between key and value!
for example:

Output:

```
The result dict is : {'Stack': '10'}
```

Well, I want the output as follows:

```
 The result dict is : {'Stack':'10'}
```

Well the zip function would give a space between them and cause me an error!

And this is the result I have to get:

```
Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma) for list1: Stack,Over,Flow
Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma) for list2: 111,222,333
{'Stack':'111','Over':'222','Flow':'333'}
```

and for the code I tried is:

```
List_1 = input('Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma): ').split(',')
List_2 = input('Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma): ').split(',')
if len(List_1) == len(List_2) and len(List_1) != 0 and len(List_2) != 0 :
     dict = dict(zip(List_1, List_2))
     print(dict)
else:
    print('The two lists are of different lengths. Try again.')
```

Comment: Why on earth is the whitespace significant?

Comment: This ```if len(List_1) == len(List_2) and len(List_1) != 0 and len(List_2) != 0```, can be shortened (and more Pythonic) as ```if all((List_1, List_2, len(List_1) == len(List_2))):```.

Comment: Building the dict does not introduce the whitespace; using `dict.__repr__` to display it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to be quite specific about the output I would do something like this:

```py
def condensed_dict(data):
    output = []
    for item in data.items():
        output.append('%r:%r' % item)
    return '{%s}' % ''.join(output)


List_1 = input('Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma): ').split(',')
List_2 = input('Enter list elements separated by ,(Comma): ').split(',')

if List_1 and len(List_1) == len(List_2):
     dict = dict(zip(List_1, List_2))
     print(condensed_dict(dict))
else:
    print('The two lists are of different lengths. Try again.')
```

PS: I simplified your if statement a bit.

Comment: This doesn't print the `{}`

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out this is a highly specific hack: if any of the items were a `dict`, then they would still be printed *with* space separating key and value.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. The entire question is rather specific if you ask me :P

Answer (score 0):

Build your own string from the zipped lists directly, rather than using a `dict`.

```
>>> "{%s}" % ",".join(f"'{k}':'{v}'" for k, v in zip(List_1, List_2))
"{'Stack':'111','Over':'222','Flow':'333'}"
```

If you already *have* the `dict`, then build the string from the output of its `items` method.

```
>>> d = dict(zip(List_1, List2))
>>> "{%s}" % ",".join(f"'{k}':'{v}'" for k, v in d.items())
"{'Stack':'111','Over':'222','Flow':'333'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    test_keys = ["Rash", "Kil", "Varsha"] 
    test_values = [1, 4, 5] 
    print ("Original key list is : " + str(test_keys)) 
    print ("Original value list is : " + str(test_values)) 
    # using zip() 
    # to convert lists to dictionary 
    res = dict(zip(test_keys, test_values))  
    print ("Resultant dictionary is : " +  str(res))
```

Comment: The output is same as before! As I asked for a specific output, and the zip function is not gonna do it.